# How to isolate a frequency range in MATLAB using signals concepts?

Tags: matlab, audio, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to use concepts learned in signals analysis to isolate a specific frequency from a sound file. I have a short WAV file that consists of a person talking but also has other noises with unknown frequencies both above and below the desired signal. I have an upper and lower bound for the frequency range that should contain the part of the sound I want.

I think I should be able to do this without using the signals analysis toolbox or the butter filter.

so far I have this code which plots the power spectrum for the signal:

```
[y, Fs] = audioread('filename.wav','double');
t = 1:1:length(y);

y = transpose(y);
a = ifft(y);
a_k = abs([a((length(y)/2)+1:-1:2),a(1:1:(length(y)/2)+1)]);
bar((-length(y)/2)+1:1:(length(y)/2),a_k);
```

The power spectrum looks like this:

[image: power spectrum]

I think I should be able to use what I have to filter our anything above or below my known range, but I am not sure how to start doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply ideal band pass filter you can use the code below. However, please note that the ideal filter may not produce the most optimal results if your signal is not periodic (see the wiki article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringing_artifacts)).

```
%% Initialisation
Fs = 44100;
t0 = 0;
t1 = 1;
t = t0 : 1/Fs : t1;

f1 = 10;
f2 = 40;
y = 10*cos(2*pi*f1*t) + 20*sin(2*pi*f2*t);

%% Cosine series

true_fft = fft(y);

nfft = length(y);

% The number of unique points
if mod(nfft, 2) == 0
    num_pts = round(nfft/2) + 1;
else
    num_pts = ceil(nfft/2);
end

% The vector that contains only unique points
fftT = true_fft(1 : num_pts);

% The vector that contains the unique frequencies
u_f = (0 : num_pts-1)*Fs/nfft;

%% Filtered signal

% Definition of the frequency band
f_low = 5;
f_high = 15;

[~, idx_low] = min(abs(u_f - f_low));
[~, idx_high] = min(abs(u_f - f_high));

filtFFTT = fftT;
filtFFTT([1: idx_low idx_high : end]) = 0;

if mod(nfft, 2) == 0
    filtFFTT = [filtFFTT conj(filtFFTT((end - 1) : -1 : 2))];
else
    filtFFTT = [filtFFTT conj(filtFFTT(end : -1 : 2))];
end


%% Data visualisation
figure;
plot(t, ifft(filtFFTT));
```